# FromBody attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a method as described below which get user as parameter.
To send the user parameter values, I am using postman request/response tool. 
My question is, if the request already have user parameter in body request  (see at the postman print screen ) why do I need to directly specify  [FromBody] in action controller? When this attribute removed,  parameter send with null values.

Thanks

[image: postman request for register action]

```
[HttpPost("register")]
 public IActionResult Register([FromBody]User user)
 {
  //.. code  here 

 }


public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string  Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You're telling the model binder where to find the `User` object.  It's not necessarily in the body

Answer (score 5):

The `[FromBody]` directive tells the Register action to look for the User parameter in the Body of the request, rather than somewhere else, like from the URL. So, removing that confuses your method, and that's why you see null values as it's not sure where to look for the `User` parameters.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api for more information/learning.

Comment: But post by default  send the data  in the body of the request  so why using [FormBody] ?

Comment: @erb601 Arguably for a POST request the default would be form data. If you wanted to read this then the model would be bound using the FromForm attribute (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding#sources) - if you decorate the controller with ApiAttribute in recent versions of .NET Core then the default is FromBody for complex types as you expect (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/index?view=aspnetcore-3.0#binding-source-parameter-inference).

Answer (score 5):

For Model Binding in ASP.NET Core, MVC and Web APi uses the same model binding pattern.

There are default model bindings like Form Values, Route values and Query Strings. If these bindings fails, it will not throw an error, and return null.

If you do not want to add `[FromBody]`, you could try Form Values binding and send request from Postman like below:

[image]

`[FromBody]` will override default data source and specify the model binder's data source from the request body.

You could refer [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1) for detail information

Comment: But post by default  send the data  in the body of the request  so why using [FormBody] ?

Comment: For `Request Body`, it could be `form-data` and `raw`. And in `Asp.Net Core`, the defult binding for `Post` is `form-data`. `form-data` and `raw` are used two different binding way. `form-data` is used name-value and `raw with json` is used with `JsonFormatter`. Only one could be default and this behavior is by design.

Comment: So , when i use the [FormBody] attribute its override the default binding ?

Comment: Yes, `[FromBody]` will change the default bebaivor for the model binding to bind model by `JsonInputFormatter`.

Answer (score -6):

the attribute [FromBody] ensures the API reads the JSON payload in the HTTP Request body. For more info, read

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: I'm not sure this answer adds anything not already in the answer from 2018? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51641444/397817

Comment: I actually think that this answer provides the basic info more clearly.